# #Error in Access query builder for calculated field

Tags: sql, ms-access

In my Access database, I've set up a query that will calculate the Required Date for a set of conditions. If the record is deceased with a relationship of spouse, it calculates the age 72 date, if the record is not a spouse if calculates 5 years from the date of death.

I'm keep getting an error when trying to account for a leap year date (2/29). Here is the calculated field:

```
AdjRequiredDate: IIf([Relationship]="Spouse",[BIRTHDATE]+26298,IIf(DatePart("m",[DeceasedDate]="2"),IIf(DatePart("d",[DeceasedDate]="29"),"3/1/" & (DatePart("y",[DeceasedDate])+1826),[DeceasedDate]+1826)))
```

it checks for the relationship and calculates if a spouse, otherwise it determines if the date of death month is a 2, if yes, is the day 29, if yes, then concatenate 3/1 with the year 5 years from the year of death. The full query, which is returning the #Error is below:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp ( SSNO, AdjRequiredDate )
SELECT tblPersonal.SSNO, IIf([Relationship]="Spouse",[BIRTHDATE]+26298,IIf(DatePart("m",[DeceasedDate]="2"),IIf(DatePart("d",[DeceasedDate]="29"),"3/1/" & (DatePart("y",[DeceasedDate])+1826),[DeceasedDate]+1826))) AS AdjRequiredDistrDate
FROM tblPersonal
WHERE (((tblPersonal.PaidDate) Is Null) AND ((tblPersonal.Relationship) Is Not Null))
ORDER BY tblPersonal.DeceasedDate;
```

Comment: Why aren't you using DateAdd() function which already does leap years?

Comment: @ChrisMaurer that wouldn't give me specific days for determining is the date is a 2/29

Comment: Iif(month([DoD])=2 and day([DoD])=29, dateadd("yyyy",5,dateadd("d",1[DoD])),...else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add *years*, not days, then `DateAdd` does it right for any date:

```
AdjRequiredDate: IIf([Relationship]="Spouse", DateAdd("yyyy", 75, [BirthDate]), DateAdd("yyyy", 5, [DeceasedDate]))
```

Also, always handle dates as *DateTime*, not text, not numbers.

For extended handling of date and time, see my library at **GitHub**: [VBA.Date](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Date).